# Split timestamp column into two seperate date and time columns with python

Tags: python, pandas, time, timestamp

I have a dataset called "df_no_missing".

```
df_no_missing.head()
```

> ```
> TIMESTAMP         object
> P_ACT_KW         float64
> PERIODE_TARIF     object
> P_SOUSCR         float64
> SITE              object
> TARIF             object
> depassement      float64
> dtype: object
> ```

I try to extract date and time into two different columns from the timestamp column, so I did :

```
dt = datetime.strptime('TIMESTAMP', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
df_no_missing['date'] = df_no_missing['TIMESTAMP'].dt.date
df_no_missing['time'] = df_no_missing['TIMESTAMP'].dt.time
```

But I got an error :

```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-185-6599284ba17f> in <module>()
>       1 print(df_no_missing.dtypes)
>       2 df_no_missing.head()
> ----> 3 dt = datetime.strptime('TIMESTAMP', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
>       4 df_no_missing['date'] = df_no_missing['TIMESTAMP'].dt.date
>       5 df_no_missing['time'] = df_no_missing['TIMESTAMP'].dt.time
> 
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py in
> _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
>     508     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
>     509     format string."""
> --> 510     tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
>     511     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
>     512     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)
> 
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py in
> _strptime(data_string, format)
>     341     if not found:
>     342         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
> --> 343                          (data_string, format))
>     344     if len(data_string) != found.end():
>     345         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
> 
> ValueError: time data 'TIMESTAMP' does not match format '%d/%m/%y
> %H:%M'
```

Here is the csv file :

```
TIMESTAMP;P_ACT_KW;PERIODE_TARIF;P_SOUSCR;SITE;TARIF    
31/07/2015 23:00;12;HC;;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
31/07/2015 23:10;466;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
31/07/2015 23:20;18;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
31/07/2015 23:30;17;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
31/07/2015 23:40;13;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
31/07/2015 23:50;13;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
01/08/2015 00:00;13;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
01/08/2015 00:10;14;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
01/08/2015 00:20;13;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
01/08/2015 00:30;20;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
```

Any idea to help me please?

Thank you in advance

Best regrads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you want:

```
df_no_missing['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df_no_missin['TIMESTAMP'], '%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
```

then you can do `.dt.time` and `dt.date` after the conversion

Also you need to post what the datetime strings look like

**EDIT**

You can tell `read_csv` to just parse your datestrings on loading:

```
In [42]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""TIMESTAMP;P_ACT_KW;PERIODE_TARIF;P_SOUSCR;SITE;TARIF
31/07/2015 23:00;12;HC;;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
31/07/2015 23:10;466;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
31/07/2015 23:20;18;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
31/07/2015 23:30;17;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
31/07/2015 23:40;13;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
31/07/2015 23:50;13;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
01/08/2015 00:00;13;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
01/08/2015 00:10;14;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
01/08/2015 00:20;13;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5
01/08/2015 00:30;20;HC;425;ST GEREON;TURPE_HTA5"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=';', parse_dates=[0])
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 6 columns):
TIMESTAMP        10 non-null datetime64[ns]
P_ACT_KW         10 non-null int64
PERIODE_TARIF    10 non-null object
P_SOUSCR         9 non-null float64
SITE             10 non-null object
TARIF            10 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 560.0+ bytes
```

So in your case:

```
df = pd.read_csv(your_file, sep=';', parse_dates=[0])
```

should just work

Comment: @EdChurn thank for your reply, but there is a probleme with this line : df_no_missing['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df_no_missing['TIMESTAMP'], '%d/%m/%y %H:%M')

Comment: it would help don't you think to tell me **what** the problem is don't you think? Also can you post raw data and code in your question to avoid ambiguities

Comment: it indicates : pandas\tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.array_to_datetime (pandas\tslib.c:38535)()

AssertionError:

Comment: As I've already stated, I and probably others can't help you unless you post raw data and code, I'm not going to look at this question further unless you provide raw data and code to demonstrate the errors

Comment: I edited my post. And the problem is that there is case, it is forbidden to publish data . You know this ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you define

```
dt = datetime.strptime(TIMESTAMP, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
```

Then the value of `TIMESTAMP` has to be like

```
TIMESTAMP = '03/08/16 16:49'
```

If the format is defined as

```
dt = datetime.strptime(TIMESTAMP, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```

then

```
TIMESTAMP = '03/08/2016 16:49'
```

should be an acceptable argument for `strptime`.